# MVVM with ReactiveCocoa, how does ViewModel tell View to do some one time operation?

Tags: ios, mvvm, reactive-cocoa

For Example, I want my view to show a toast, the way I'm doing it now is like:

in view:

```
RACObserve(self.viewModel, showToast) subscribeNext:^(NSNumber *isShow) {
    if (isShow.boolValue) {
        self showToast];
    }
}
```

`showToast` is a property of my ViewModel, I don't think this way is very descriptive, is there any more standard, more elegant way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give something more descriptive, you could create a RACSubject to manually send notifications using `[self.toastsSubject sendNext:@"Toast info string of some kind"]`.

```
@weakify(self)
[self.viewModel.toastsSubject subscribeNext:^(id _) {
    @strongify(self)
    [self showToast];
}
```

Even better, you could have showToast take a single argument (such as the content of the toast), then you don't need to use `@weakify` and `@strongify`, instead could you lift the signal directly using `rac_liftSelector`.

```
[self rac_liftSelector:@selector(showToast:)
      withSignals:self.viewModel.toastsSubject, nil];
```